# send Data from react to django rest api

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, react-hooks

after a lot of searching i keep finding how to send Data from react to django api using classes not functions so how would i convert this for exmaple to a functional component (this is not my code, just an example)

```
    export default class CreateRoomPage extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          guestCanPause: this.props.guestCanPause,
          votesToSkip: this.props.votesToSkip,
          errorMsg: "",
          successMsg: "",
        };
        this.handleRoomButtonPressed = this.handleRoomButtonPressed.bind(this);
        this.handleVotesChange = this.handleVotesChange.bind(this);
      }

      handleGuestCanPauseChange(e) {
        this.setState({
          guestCanPause: e.target.value === "true" ? true : false,
        });
      }

    handleRoomButtonPressed() {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          votes_to_skip: this.state.votesToSkip,
          guest_can_pause: this.state.guestCanPause,
        }),
      };
      fetch("/api/create-room", requestOptions)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => this.props.history.push("/room/" + data.code));
    }

    renderCreateButtons() {
      return (
        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          <Grid item xs={12} align="center">
            <Button
              color="primary"
              variant="contained"
              onClick={this.handleRoomButtonPressed}
            >
              Create A Room
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      );
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im learning as well, my approach:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router";


export default function CreateRoomPage () {

const history = useHistory();

const [guestCanPause, setGuestCanPause] = useState(true)
const [votesToSkip, setVotesToSkip] = useState(1)

const handleGuestCanPauseChange = () => {
  setGuestCanPause(current => !current)
}

const handleVotesChange = (e) => {
  setVotesToSkip(e.target.value)
 }

const handleRoomButtonPressed = async () => {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      votes_to_skip: votesToSkip,
      guest_can_pause: guestCanPause,
    }),
  };
  await fetch("/api/create-room", requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => history.push("/room/" + data.code));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest learning React classes and DRF before trying to learn React functional components and hooks, simply because there are a lot more resources for learning class-based React.

If you did, you'd know that there is nothing special about converting this particular code to a functional component. Just lose "this" and declare the methods as functions (arrow functions/classic functions - it doesn't matter)

PS: There is nothing to lose by learning class-based React - it's almost the same, and most of the differences will help understand how React works/how classes work on computers (arguably important for any programmer).

Comment: yeah, i did realize that there is a LOT more recources for class-based React,but i also heard that functional component are far superior so i thought it would be better to learn that from the start

Comment: I do prefer functional components because of their higher ability to compartmentalize different effects and logic, but I wouldn't say they're far superior. If you ever find that you have to use React 'higher-order components' or 'render props', that would be a good time to use more functional components.

Comment: Ok, i will settel for classes for now but if anyone could still show me how to converte the code to functional component that would be greate.